# Document Management System in .NET

Tags: .net, document-management, dms

does anyone know about a document management system (or modules) that can be integrated with .NET?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to use Sharepoint? That would provide a lot of functionality with little coding on your part, though you'd have to do configuration.

Comment: @DOK: sounds like an answer to me, any reason you haven't posted it as answer?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list of some of the most common DMS found in enterprises nowadays.
(they all could be integrated to .net)

1. EMC
2. Hummingbird
3. Open Text
4. Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services
5. Xerox DocuShare
6. UCM by Oracle
7. FileNet by IBM
8. Interwoven WorkSite

Comment: I've worked on EMC (both eRoom and Documentum), Hummingbird DM, OpenText LiveLink, Xerox DocuShare & Microsoft SharePoint. I can tell you that SharePoint is the only one the is easy to work with .Net Framework. LiveLink has an acceptable API, but secure conenction is limited... eRoom/Documentum/DocuShare all have have terrible APIs....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what kind of integration you are after. If you're looking for a stand alone solution which has an API interface usable from .Net languages I can't help mentioning [M-Files](http://www.m-files.com/eng/home.asp). Though I need to mention this recommendation might be extremely biased.

The system is commercial but there is a free version available with some limitations such as user amount etc. I believe.

The API is a pretty solid COM api which works quite smoothly through COM interop. It's strongly typed etc. so using it from .Net gives no troubles unlike some other COM apis. (*Cough..Office..Cough*) Internally the API is used to provide a web interface as an alternative to the native Windows integration so it's kept up to date and usable for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

The old classic is [Dot Net Nuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/). There is a big community around the modules and of course you can write your own. Best of all it's open source.

Comment: I don't think DNN is particularly suited to DMS tasks. Just because you *can* write a module to do anything doesn't really mean much. It seems much more geared to WCM than DM.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SiteFinity](http://www.telerik.com/products/sitefinity.aspx), or [Graffiti](http://graffiticms.com/). I'm currently evaluating both of these as a potential solution for our site.

Comment: Those are both WCM systems, not DM systems. Do they have DM add-ons?

Comment: The difference between CM and DM is a bit gray when it comes to .NET. Since they didn't specify any details I thought I'd point them to some other tools. Sitefinity comes mighty close to an online document system.

Answer (score 0):

If cost is no issue and you can use a standard DMS pretty much out of the box (e.g. only minor custom development), [Microsoft Office Sharepoint Server](http://www.microsoft.com/Sharepoint/default.mspx) is great for document management and document-based team collaboration. Creating workspaces, integration with Office products (for example, you can save your Word and Excel work directly into your collaboration space on the Sharepoint server). For end-users who are already proficient in the Office suite, it's a very pleasant UX.

That having been said, there are two caveats - it is insanely expensive, and deep, core customizations are more than a little painful. Superficial widget-type customization is a breeze though.

Comment: Windows Sharepoint Services is included with Windows 2008 Server, and it comes with all of the basic document management capabilities of MOSS. No additional licensing is required, provided you use it on the corporate intranet only (i.e. you don't need a web-facing server).