# Is there any Document Management Component (Commercial or Open Source) for .NET?

Tags: .net, dms

We are building a .NET web application (case management) and one of the requirement it needs to have a Document Management System to store and manage the document and at the same time it can be used out side this application such as intranet. Rather than inventing the wheel to do this, is there any Document Management System component that can be integrated with .NET? I preferred the commercial one but if there is open source I am more than happy.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you come across Sharepoint?  Perhaps its way OTT for what you need.

Also see this question:-

[Document Management System in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817751/document-management-system-in-net)

Comment: Here is a nice blog that might interest people wanting to use sharepoint for managing documents:
http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2007/10/31/sharepoint-sucks-at-document-management-or-does-it-a-metal-perspective/

Answer (score 1):

Did you think of a solution based on [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/). You could use SharpSVN (.NET) to create your own Document management based on it. Advantages:

- Rights can be managed in SVN for access rights
- You can attach any information you want to the documents means SVN properties
- It is fully open source and actively used/maintained
- Links can be created with "externals"
- You can create baselines for your documents easily by branching/tagging
- Subversion makes binary diffs and so you minimize the backup overhead.
- Document retrieval might be a bit slow but usually users want the latest version of a doc and this could be solved by using the local copy or caching.

Comment: I know there is a bunch of work to be done if you choose this :-) but then it'll be all in your hand!